# Console flooded with CFNetwork and DataDetectorsUI logs

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cfnetwork, nsdatadetector

Ever since I've updated to Xcode 15.2 (I'm currently using Xcode 15.3) my console gets flooded with logs from `CFNetwork` and `DataDetectorsUI`. I've never seen those logs before. Is there a way to suppress them? I can't even find my own logs anymore without filters.

#### CFNetwork

```
Task <50C80E0E-9DA5-428F-A473-9D0228088022>.<4> resuming, timeouts(25.0, 604800.0) QOS(0x15) Voucher (null)
[Telemetry]: Activity <nw_activity 12:2[78557FD1-54F3-4B77-8C5C-57F500D67286] (reporting strategy default)> on Task <50C80E0E-9DA5-428F-A473-9D0228088022>.<4> was not selected for reporting
Connection 29: set is idle false
Task <50C80E0E-9DA5-428F-A473-9D0228088022>.<4> now using Connection 29
Task <50C80E0E-9DA5-428F-A473-9D0228088022>.<4> sent request, body S 535
Task <50C80E0E-9DA5-428F-A473-9D0228088022>.<4> received response, status 201 content U
Task <50C80E0E-9DA5-428F-A473-9D0228088022>.<4> done using Connection 29
Connection 29: set is idle true
HTTP/2 Connection 29 Stream 7 ended successfully true
Task <50C80E0E-9DA5-428F-A473-9D0228088022>.<4> request *** is NOT allowed to set HSTS for main doc (null)
Task <50C80E0E-9DA5-428F-A473-9D0228088022>.<4> response ended
Task <50C80E0E-9DA5-428F-A473-9D0228088022>.<4> finished successfully
Connection 19: cleaning up
Connection 19: done
Applying proxy auth: response=(null), proxyURL=(null), request=(null), credentials=(null), handle=0x11c2f7d30
Connection 21: cleaning up
Connection 23: cleaning up
Connection 22: cleaning up
```

#### DataDetectorsUI

```
operation 0x10ff7e560
operation 0x10ff7e560 is discarded
Calling the completion block for 0x10ff7e560
dispatchScanQueryCreationWithCompletionBlock of operation <DDTextKitOperation: 0x10ff7e560> completion block: success: 0
operation 0x10ff7e560
operation 0x10ff7e560
operation 0x10fb2f850
really creating scan query in operation 0x10fb2f850!
operation 0x10fb2f850
```

Comment: It turned out that it had something to do with the iPhone I was using to run the project on. It was on 17.1.1. I updated it to 17.4 and now those logs are gone. Not sure though what was going on ...